# node rest client get with local variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, node-rest-client

I am trying to do the following:

```
var id=9;
            client.get("http://localhost:5000/api/produto/{id}", function (data, response) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("------------");
                console.log(response);
            });
```

but it says that :

```
{ id: [ 'The value \'{id}\'\' is not valid.' ] }
```

I want to know how can I use a local variable in the get request ?
I am requesting to a project I've made and if I put a number instead of id it works.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var id=9;
            client.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/produto/${id}`, function (data, response) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("------------");
                console.log(response);
            });
```

It's called template literals:

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (` `)  (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes. Template literals can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (${expression}). The expressions in the placeholders and the text between them get passed to a function. The default function just concatenates the parts into a single string. If there is an expression preceding the template literal (tag here), this is called a "tagged template". In that case, the tag expression (usually a function) gets called with the processed template literal, which you can then manipulate before outputting. To escape a back-tick in a template literal, put a backslash \ before the back-tick.
```